# How to make a drop down menu

Tags: hyperref

Is it possible to make a drop down menu so that following a link, say provided by `\href`, results in a set of choices overlaying the current page?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

There is a [popupmenu](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/popupmenu) package. Here's a portion of the README file:

> `popupmenu` is a LaTeX package used to create a menu structure. This
>   menu structure (an array of menu items) is passed to the Acrobat
>   JavaScript method app.popUpMenuEx() method to create a popup menu.
>   Using the environments defined in this package, and the command
>   `\popUpMenu`, you can create and display hierarchical menus. The menu
>   items can have JavaScript actions associated with them, they can be
>   marked and dis-enabled.

Some examples can be found in CTAN [here](http://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/popupmenu/examples) and should also be part of a MiKTeX distribution (the package is not part of TeX Live).

Comment: What? I seriously did not expect to see an actual solution to this