# How to create Windows-8-styled menus?

Tags: formatting, windows

I'm writing a technical documentation and I want to explain step-by-step how to go through various menus.

For example I used to write `Open with > VLC media player`.

That's how it looks in Windows 8:

[image: menu style in Windows 8]

What I want in Latex should looks similar to this: light grey box, dark grey border and black windows-like font.

[image: Desired result]

I've seen [this question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/53508/14076), suggesting the package [`popupmenu`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/popupmenu) - but it looks very old fashioned - are there any more modern approaches?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

How about the [menukeys](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/menukeys) package?

```
\usepackage[os=win]{menukeys}
....
\menu{{Open with}>{VLC media player}}
```

Output:

[image]

Comment: After the meme 'there's an app for that', now we, TeX enthusiasts have: 'there's a package for that'! `:D`